# Spring integration how to poll cron expression adapter in xml

Tags: xml, spring, cron, spring-integration

I'm trying to migrate cron scheduler that takes in 2 cron expressions (Expression and Timezone).
I checked the spring integration docs and there seems to be a constructor that takes in exactly what I need https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/dsl/PollerFactory.html#cron(java.lang.String,java.util.TimeZone) PollerSpec cron(String cronExpression, TimeZone timeZone). But, I'm not sure how to implement it in xml.

```
<int:inbound-channel-adapter channel="cronInput">
<int:integration:PollerSpec cronExpression=${bless.cron.expression}" timeZone= "${bless.cron.timezone}"/>
</int:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:channel id="cronInput" />
```

Here's how I implemented it and my understanding is it's taking the message payload from executing the cron expression and putting it in the pipe/channel cronInput, so If I create another endpoint like activator, I can create an input channel and use the payload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PollerSpec` is for Java DSL. It has nothing to do with an XML. And there is indeed no `PollerSpec` custom XML tag.

The `<int:inbound-channel-adapter>` comes with a `<int:poller>` sub-element:

```
<xsd:element name="poller" type="basePollerType"/>
```

This `poller` custom tag comes with this attribute:

```
    <xsd:attribute name="cron" type="xsd:string">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>Cron trigger.</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:attribute>
```

However there is no `TimeZone` attribute to cover your other use-case.

Nevertheless the `<poller>` can be configured with a `trigger` attribute:

```
    <xsd:attribute name="trigger" type="xsd:string">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:appinfo>
                <tool:annotation kind="ref">
                    <tool:expected-type type="org.springframework.scheduling.Trigger"/>
                </tool:annotation>
            </xsd:appinfo>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:attribute>
```

So, for your use case you can provide an extra `CronTrigger` and use its bean name in the mentioned reference:

```
<int:inbound-channel-adapter channel="cronInput">
    <int:poller trigget="cronTrigger"/>
</int:inbound-channel-adapter>

<beans:bean id="cronTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronTrigger">
    <beans:constructor-arg value="${bless.cron.expression}"/>
    <beans:constructor-arg value="${bless.cron.timezone}"/>
</beans:bean>
```

From here the question from me: why do you try to implement this stuff with an XML?
Why just don't go ahead and just deal with Java DSL or at least an Annotations configuration?